# Can't Change button or panel location in Swing (Java)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, location

I can't change the location of Button or Panel in "setbounds" in java swing.It's just stuck to the top. What should I change here? Should I add a "Gridlayout" to the button or something? Changing the panel location does nothing for the button.

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Declaring In-Game Variables
    final int[] cookieamount = {1};

    // Creating the components
    JLabel cookiecounter = new JLabel();
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    JButton cookiebutton = new JButton();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();


    // Window Properties
    window.setSize(900, 550);
    window.setTitle("Cooke Clicker");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    // Panel Properties
    panel.setBounds(1,1,350,350);
    panel.setBackground(new Color(24, 44, 44));

    // Cookie Counter Properties
    cookiecounter.setLocation(50,50);
    cookiecounter.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    cookiecounter.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 60));

    // Cookie Button Properties
    cookiebutton.setBounds(200,200,300,300);
    cookiebutton.setSize(150,50);
    cookiebutton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("assets/cookie.png"));
    cookiebutton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    cookiebutton.setFocusPainted(false);
    cookiebutton.setBorder(null);

    // Set Cookie Counter text to amount of cookies

    cookiebutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cookieamount[0]++;
            cookiecounter.setText(String.valueOf(cookieamount[0]));
        }
    });



    // Adding Components to window
    window.setContentPane(panel);
    window.add(cookiecounter);
    panel.add(cookiebutton);
    window.getContentPane();
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The layout manager will set the size/location of each component based on the rules of the layout manager. *What should I change here?* - You told us what happens, but you haven't told us what you expect to happen.  Do you want the components centered both vertically and horizontally? Do you want them on separate lines? You need to explain the requirement when you ask a question. Also, you add(...) statements are wrong. You should be adding both components to the panel and the panel to the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java Swing, a layout manager decides on where the contained components are getting placed. The default layout of a JFrame is `BorderLayout` which places the components in regions around the border (or center).

If you want to place your components freely, you have to "disable" your layout.

```
window.setLayout(null);
```

This should work as intended.

Comment: (1-) The default layout manager of the frame is the BorderLayout. The default layout manager of a JPanel is a FlowLayout. When you add a component to the frame it will be added to the content pane. Since the panel is set as the content pane you have effectively changed the layout manager from BorderLayout to FlowLayout.